# Is deleting all mergeinfo a viable way to start fresh while preserving history?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I work on a team which uses SVN to maintain the code for our website.  The team has been using SVN for a couple of years, but has recently overhauled SVN practices and now operates a little differently.

As background information:

- `trunk` is auto-deployed to production, this means it always has to be clean.
- `dev` is where most bugfixes, minor tweaks, minor (1 page) features are worked on
- `xxx-dev` we have several other branches which are used for more extensive feature development, they're all named xxx-dev where xxx is the name of the feature.
- Every day, sync merges are run from `trunk` -> all other branches. This is a bit tedious but keeps our branches in sync with what's in `trunk` while minimizing the number of conflicts I have to resolve when we sync things up. Changes are deployed to trunk every day by different people so it is necessary to keep all the branches up to date. I use tortoise and I leave the revision range box blank so that all un-merged revisions are merged into the branches from `trunk`.

Recently, something went wrong with a deployment from an older branch (last year all kinds of bad things were happening in our merge history due to improperly performed merges, skipped revisions, etc). I can't figure out exactly what happened, but I can no longer sync merge from trunk into our branches. It attempts to re-merge some older revisions which have already been merged, and fails to do so and gives me all kinds of errors if I try to push through it. Prior to this incident, we've had numerous issues with these older revisions breaking things in the merging process, and we've proceeded by deleting branches and re-creating them from trunk. However, this might preserve merge history, and I'm worried that we need to lose our merge history altogether to get away from these problems.

Given the above information, I think our best course of action would be to drop all merge history altogether, use a fresh copy of the code from `trunk`, recreate all our branches by copying that fresh `trunk`, and proceed as we have been, but without any of the bad merge history from before we started doing daily syncs.

**My question:** To do what I've described, should we just do a recursive delete of the svn:mergeinfo property on the entire `trunk` directory? Would that cause any problems? I believe since `trunk` is underneath the repository's root directory, we would still be able to look at the old merge history if for some reason we needed to.

If I am wrong or there is something wrong with our SVN policies, please tell me as well.

Thank you!

---

Edit:  I should have mentioned that the conflict I'm seeing happens to be on the `svn:mergeinfo` property itself... So there's a bad merge that was modifying `svn:mergeinfo` I don't know how or why anyone on the team would have accidentally deleted the `svn:mergeinfo` property for this directory, but the change that seems to be causing all the problems this time is a deleted `svn:mergeinfo` property.

This deleted `svn:mergeinfo` is on a subdirectory, not the root directory of the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To do what I've described, should we just do a recursive delete of the svn:mergeinfo property on the entire trunk directory?

Yes, you can do that. You will loose all mergeinfo (of course), but afterwards, things should go smoothly until the next time someone does something "fancy" (like doing a subtree merge, which can be the entrance gate to all kinds of issues).

> Would that cause any problems?

Well, if you find a sane way to recreate all branches (basically, you will have to create new branches from the clean trunk and merge all changes in the original branches by hand to their replacements).

However, I think there are at least two options that you should consider as well:

1. Fix the `svn:mergeinfo` property by hand. If it is just one set of old merges that are (wrongly) merged from the trunk to the branches, why don't you amend the mergeinfo property in your trunk/branches by hand (or use the `--record-only` flag to make Subversion do it for you)?
2. If (1) is not an option, you should see if really all branches are affected. If not, you only need to recreate those, potentially saving you a lot of work in comparison to just replacing everything.

Hope that helps. My advice for the future: explicitly forbid subtree merges in your group and do commit reviews (e.g. have at least one other developer look over the changes in a branch before it is merged). What might be even better is to use `git` instead, although I know that this is not the best option (or even a viable one) for everyone.

**EDIT**
In response to the edit in the question: if you only have problems with subtree mergeinfo, then the solution is even easier: given that all your branches are copies of the trunk (and not subtree branches), just go ahead and delete all `svn:mergeinfo` properties for all subtrees in your repository, including trunk.

We had to do the exact same thing once: basically we checked out the complete repository, manually (or scripted) the deletion of the `svn:mergeinfo` property for all folders except trunk and branch roots, and then committed again. Afterwards, no more problems :)

Comment: I would really like to fix the MergeInfo but I'm not 100% sure what is wrong with it. I'm not confident that changes that I make won't cause weird merge issues later. Can't messing with the MergeInfo incorrectly cause later merges to mangle files or make changes that we didn't make?

Comment: I updated my question with some pertinent info.  The merge that I'm attempting to do is attempting to merge a revision which deletes mergeinfo for a subdirectory. This is strange because that revision is marked by tortoise as having already been merged, so I don't know why it's trying to merge it again.   Also, we're looking towards switching to Mercurial in the future to avoid these merging issues, but for now we're using SVN.

Comment: Hey Michael, I went ahead and did a recursive delete of `mergeinfo`, then re-added it just on the top level of each branch using backed up values. This has re-enabled our sync merges, and appears to have been the right step to take, but now I'm concerned about revisions that were merged on subtrees not showing up as merged anymore. Do you know if that's a possibility? Or does merging on a subtree also add that `mergeinfo` to the top level directory?

Comment: No, it won't show up. However, depending on how many branches you have, this should wear out pretty soon as people might have to manually fix some merges, but at some point all kinks will be worked out and things *just work* again.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So far things have been smooth since the mergeinfo delete. We're down to just 2 branches at this point in development, which is why we picked now to do these changes. Thanks for your help.